# Failure using configure of nccmp

Tags: linux, path, configure, netcdf

I would like to install the nccmp program to compare netCDF files.

Checking the documentation, the installation follows the typical structure:

./configure
  make
  make check
  make install
  make clean

However, I'm stuck in the first step because the configure is not able to find my netCDF libraries. But I don't know why.

My libs are not in the default folder, I've installed them in /opt. But I've included the path of the netCDF libs in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.

I tried also to create a link in the default lib folder to my netCDF libs

```
ln /opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib/libnetcdf.so /usr/lib/libnetcdf.so
ln /opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib/libnetcdff.so /usr/lib/libnetcdff.so
ln /opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib/libnetcdf.a /usr/lib/libnetcdf.a
ln /opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib/libnetcdff.a /usr/lib/libnetcdff.a
```

But it doesn't work either. I explicitly used the path in the call

```
./configure --libdir=/opt/netCDF/
```

I set LIBS and LDFLAGS to

```
LDFLAGS=-L/opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib/
LIBS=/opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib/
```

and execute configure then, but with the same bad results:

```
checking for nc_open in -lnetcdf... no
configure: error: in `/opt/nccmp':
configure: error: Required NetCDF library not found!
```

In the config.log I see:

configure:3763: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c -lnetcdf  -lm  >&5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf4_la-nc4file.o): In function `nc4_rec_read_types':
/opt/NETCDF_BUILD/netcdf-4.2.1.1/libsrc4/nc4file.c:1850: undefined reference to`H5Gget_create_plist'

and many more similar lines like that one...

I don't know what else to try, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It also needs to find the HDF5 libraries, because you probably compiled netCDF with version 4 support. You should set that in `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, like `LDFLAGS='-L/opt/netcdf-4.2.1.1/lib -L/opt/hdf5/lib'`.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the problem... I needed, as expected, to define LDFLAGS and CFLAGS in my shell and **export** them to allow the access of configure to those variables.